# Flutter on tap map marker not working in iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps-markers, device, fluttermap

When using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) and [flutter_map_marker_cluster](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map_marker_cluster) to build map with marker I have a problem that sometimes but in quite long duration onTap not working anymore but it only occurred in iOS device. In android and iOS simulator it works normally.

```
Flutter Map {
   layers: [
        // Layer map cluster marker ---> HERE
        MapCluster.getMapCluster(mapStateNotifier, mapState),
      ],
   children: [
        // map tile layer
        TileLayerWidget(),

        // Location user marker
        CircleLayerWidget(),

        // Compass marker
        MarkerLayerWidget(),
      ],
}
```

```
// inside method MapCluster.getMapCluster 
return MarkerClusterLayerOptions(
    // void Function(Marker)?
    onMarkerTap: (Marker marker) {
        // ---> HERE
        // show popup
    }

);
```

I have tried

1. Increase size of Marker
2. Remove other layer, just only marker layer
3. Search issue in Flutter marker cluster package

I realized that running debug even not jump to break point inside onMarkerTap method when I tap on device. Sometimes it show smoothly, sometimes it so lag even though how many times I touch, it doesn't depend on zoom in/ out, go to background or sync/ async.

Because only iOS device has issue I think 2 packages flutter map & flutter marker cluster conflicts when handling gesture onTap in iOS but I have not find any evidence yet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out. The reason is when using FlutterCompass I called StreamSubscription in `init state` and it always be called when rotate or shaking phone.

```
  _compassStream = FlutterCompass.events?.listen((event) {
       // update state with new value event.heading
  });
```

Solution:

- Separate state management of compass widget
- Init the first time, paused and resume appropriately with flag variable.